# How can i integrate to get and send messages of skype and icq in my android app

Tags: android, skype, icq

I want to integrate skype and icq messages in my android app. Means if any one send message that msg has to come my android app and sending reply to that app only. In the same way icq also.

I google for 2days but i didn't find any solution on this. Is there any way of this.

Thanks&Regards

shankar

Answer (score 0):

If they have api for android you can do it easily. Most likely you cant do something like that easily because as I know they dont have available api for android. I dont think ink you can achive this with any other way neither

Comment: Yes, They are not provided any API. If any one have the api please i want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this php script and make a server or you can do this by using nodejs icq bot.Icq don't provide any api for direct messenging.

```
<?php

require_once('WebIcqPro.class.php');

$uin = '******';
$pass = '******';
$to_uin = '******';

$icq = new WebIcqPro();
$icq->debug = true;
$this->setTimeout(60, 60000);
$icq->setOption('UserAgent', 'miranda');
if ($icq->connect($uin, $pass)) {
    $icq->sendMessage($to_uin, 'Hello! This is a test message');
} else {
    die('ICQ connection error: ' . $icq->error);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options:

1. Check with the Skype and ICQ app if they have an API
2. Use the SHARE intent and hope both apps react to it. Negative points is that the resulting app is launched when sharing.